# get column with same name from multiple tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

i have two tables:
USERS(id, name, email, password)
QUESTIONS(id, userid, type, ques, date, time)

i have to pass the value of questions.id as qid. 
i am unable to get the desired result with the following code. instead of taking 'id' value of QUESTIONS table, it is taking the 'id' value of USERS table, and therby producing wrong output.

```
$query = "
SELECT *
     , q.id qid 
  FROM questions q
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = q.userid 
 WHERE type = 'technical' 
 ORDER 
    BY date
     , time DESC
 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$id = $_SESSION['id'];  
$ques=$row['question'];
$user = $row['username'];

    echo strtoupper($user);

    echo "<a href='allview.php?qid=$row[id]' class='class4'> $ques </a>";

}
?>
```

Comment: 1. Don't use evil `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code

```
$query = "
SELECT *
     , q.id AS qid,
       q.id AS id
  FROM questions q
```

Comment: it had to be: 'questions.id AS id'. now m getting the result! thanx  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Refers to the `id` column in the `select`.  That `id` comes from the users table.

You have renamed the question id to `qid`, so try:

```
$qid = $_SESSION['qid'];
```

A word of advice: only fetch the columns you are actually going to use:

```
SELECT u.username, q.id as qid
FROM questions q JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = q.userid
WHERE type = 'technical' 
ORDER BY date, time DESC;
```

The `*` is handy when debugging, but the code could end up behaving unexpectedly at some point because the underlying table structure changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$query = "
SELECT *
     , questions.id qid 
  FROM questions q
  , users u
 WHERE q.userid = u.id
 AND type = 'technical' 
 ORDER 
    BY date
     , time DESC
 ";
```

Comment: still 'qid' takes the value 'id' of USERS table instead of QUESTIONS table!

Comment: it had to be: 'questions.id AS id'. now m getting the result! thanx for your effort :-)